# AppHarbor Email SMTP Server Connection Issues

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, appharbor

I have to connect to a remote SMTP server (MS Exchange) to send emails through with my application deployed to AppHarbor.  In order for me to set things up correctly on the SMTP server, I need to specify an IP address requests will be coming in through.  I tried using the IP address I used to configure my DNS settings, but that didn't help.

The reason I used this SMTP server was because when I used my Google Apps SMTP configuration, emails were being blocked so I used the Exchange server inside the companies infrastructure so emails wouldn't be rejected.

Is there any other way I can connect to the SMTP server with my application on AppHarbor or do  I have to take another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We maintain a list of [AppHarbor application server IP addresses](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/application-server-ips-ec2-configuration). We recommend you use one of the [email add-ons](https://appharbor.com/addons) though.